# Java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while using ALertDialog.create

Tags: android

We have an app which has large amount of users and is keeping tract of the crush ration at one monitoring platform. Recently the ratio of java.util.ConcurrentModificationException happens much more than before(about 0.3% for this crush) .

```
Thread Name: 'main'
Back traces starts.
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at cm.org.O00Oo0.oO0Oo0o.OoO0oo0.e1$a.invoke(:2)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
    at android.app.$Proxy33.getService(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.SystemServiceRegistry.getSystemService(SystemServiceRegistry.java:949)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.getSystemService(ContextImpl.java:1697)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getSystemService(ContextThemeWrapper.java:171)
    at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5835)
    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getSystemService(ContextThemeWrapper.java:171)
    at com.huawei.android.hardware.HwSensorManager.<init>(HwSensorManager.java:254)
    at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwDialogStubImpl.<init>(HwDialogStubImpl.java:156)
    at com.huawei.android.hwcontrol.HwWidgetFactoryImpl.newHwDialogStub(HwWidgetFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at android.hwcontrol.HwWidgetFactory.getHwDialogStub(HwWidgetFactory.java:213)
    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:278)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:201)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:1093)
    at com.m1905.mobilefree.activity.MyHistoryActivity.onClick(SourceFile:18)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5709)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22627)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:846)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:205)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1216)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1077)
```

Java code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.tv_delete:
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("确认删除？").setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("确认", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            doDeleteSelected();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("取消", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).create();
            alertDialog.show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating your `AlertDialog` on the main thread? You seem to have cut off the stack trace before it got to your code. Please make sure to include the entire stack trace.

Comment: At least share the code lines at which the crash happened. We need to know what's going on in your code, not just the stacktrace.

Comment: You can wrap your code with try and catch to prevent crashing the app. You can also try creating your AlertDialog on any thread other than the main thread, but then show it on the main thread. Another thing you could try is to use "getApplicationContext()" for the AlertDialog rather than the activity context itself (I know you need the theme). Btw, the "setCancelable()" is true by default. What is exactly being clicked ? Is it a list from a RecyclerView ?

Comment: Don't you have iteration process in the `doDeleteSelected();`? This concurrent exception occurred in any ArrayList operation. You should share that method.

Comment: This concurrent exception occurred in AlertDialog.Builder.create function, not in the doDeleteSelected